# C code, scanf and getchar

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I'm just asking what does the getchar do in this code and how does it work? I don't understand why the getchar affects the code, to me it seems as if its just getting the value but nothing is being done with the value.

```
int c=0;
while (c>=0)
{
  scanf("%d", &c);
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: Hint: try with `char` type. Here , it's redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Some possibilities of why `getchar()` might have been used there:

1) If it's done to ignore whitespaces (typically used when scanning chars with `%c`), it's not needed here because `%d` ignores whitespaces anyway.

2) Other possibility is that *after* this loop, some further scanning is done where the last `\n` left by the last call to `scanf()` might be a problem. So, `getchar()` might be used to ignore it.

3) In case you enter characters do not match `%d`, `scanf()` will fail. In that the characters you entered are left in the input stream and you'll never be able to read an `int` again (For example, if you input `abcdddgdfg` without that `getchar()` call). So, `getchar()` here will consume all those 
chars (one per iteration) and eventually you'll be able to read `int` (using `%d`) again.

But this is all really not needed; it's just an attempt to fix flaws of `scanf()`. Reading inputs using `scanf()` and getting it correct is *really* difficult. That's why it's always recommended to use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) and parse using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or using [`strto*()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) functions if you are just scanning integers.

See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Answer (score 1):

In this code, `getchar` is being called for its side effects: it reads a character from standard input and throws it away.

Probably this is reading input from the user.  `scanf` will consume a number, but leave the newline character after the number untouched.  The `getchar` consumes the newline and throws it away.  This isn't strictly necessary in this loop, because the *next* `scanf` will skip over whitespace to find the next number, but it might be useful if the code *after* the loop isn't expecting to have a newline as the first thing on stdin.

This code is buggy, because it doesn't check for EOF, because it doesn't do anything sensible when the input is *not* a number or when there's more text on the line after the number, and because it uses `scanf`, which is broken-as-specified (for instance, it's allowed to *crash the program* if the input overflows the range of an `int`).  Better code would be something like

```
char *linep = 0;
size_t asize = 0;
char *endp;
long c;
while (getline(&linep, &asize, stdin) > 0) {
    errno = 0;
    c = strtol(linep, &endp, 10);
    if (linep == endp || *endp != '\0' || errno) {
        puts("?Redo from start");
        continue;
    }
    if (c == 0) break;
    do_something_with(c);
}
free(linep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the code is for reading in a list of integers, separated by a new line.

scanf will read in an integer, and put it into variable c.

The getchar is reading in the next character (assuming a new line)

Since it doesn't check, there is some potential that it wasn't a new line, or that scanf failed as the what it tried to read wasn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar();` is simply reading and consuming the character after the number, be it a space, comma, new line or the beginning of another integer or anything else.

IMO, this is not robust code.  Good code would 1) at least test the result of `scanf()` and 2) test or limit the consumption of the following character to prevent "eating" a potential sign of the following number.  Remember code cannot control what a user types, but has to cope with whatever is entered.

```
    v space
"123 456"

    v comma
"123,456"

    v negative sign
"123-456"
```